# use scaled_vel_traj_controller in moveit_config

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the use of `ur_robot_driver`, I have been using `scaled_pos_traj_controller` in the `ros_controllers.yaml` file. Now I want to use `scaled_vel_traj_controller`. Simply changing the `action_ns:` in the `ros_controllers.yaml` file does not work. `Moveit` keep waiting for the `scaled_vel_traj_controller` to come up.
I have found a `ur5_controllers.yaml` in the `config` folder under `ur_robot_driver`. How to adapt this to be used?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361525/use-scaled_vel_traj_controller-in-moveit_config/) by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has been found that in the `planning_execution.launch` file, one should have included `ur5_bringup.launch`. There, one of the tags `controllers`, one of the default controllers to be activated was `scaled_pos_traj_controller`. Changing it to `scaled_vel_traj_controller` will bring up the `scaled_vel_traj_controller`. One should do the same for the `stopped_controllers` tag.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) with karma: 53 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0